# Unable to get windows login name of the user?

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows

In my ASP.NET application deployed on an intranet, I am using something like this in a Web Service to get the Windows Login of the current user:

```
string user = User.Identity.Name.ToString();
```

and added the following to my `Web.config` file:

```
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <identity impersonate="false" />
</system.web>
```

This works when I deploy my site locally but does not work when I publish it and use an actual URL (not the localhost) to access it. Am I missing something? I want to get the Windows Login name of the user currently accessing my website. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

Has Windows Authentication been set in IIS?

You may need a combination of Basic and Windows Authentication being set in IIS for this to work properly.

Answer (score 1):

Does your service actually have any authentication requirements?  Most services require some negotiation for the authentication (like if it is SOAP or passed in HTTP headers, etc.).

What client are you using to execute the service call?  A browser can pass the Windows credentials if it is in a trusted connection (like intranet or localhost), but if you are calling the service on an untrusted domain from the browser, or using a different client you need to pass the credentials differently.

Comment: My service does not strictly need the authentication service. I am using this to populate a field in a submission form. I am using an ASP page accessed through a browser. I will look into the untrusted domain issue because I am accessing the URI from a machine in the same domain.